# How to wait for another service to finish a task in the background without awaiting?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, autodesk-forge

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core WebApi, which uses the Autodesk Model Derivative API to convert a Revit file into another file format. After I've uploaded the file, the Autodesk API starts working in the background and can take several minutes to finish its work.

I want to monitor the status of the Autodesk API, to know if the conversion has been finished yet and notify the user. I'm looking for the best way to monitor the status of the job without 'awaiting' and letting the request hang stuck for several minutes.

I've tried just running the task asynchronously without awaiting the result. This worked, up to the point where I wanted to update a value in my Database Context, because that had been disposed due to the request having ended.

I've also researched several options on implementing background services, but haven't found a clear way to do that.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Response<JobResponse>>> UploadFile(string bucketKey, IFormFile file)
{
    // ....
    // File has been uploaded 
    Response<JobResponse> response
        = await NetworkManager.PostAsync<JobResponse>(URI.Job.Url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jobData));

    // The job has been created in the Autodesk API, so I create a record in my own database
    var job = new Job(urn, file.FileName);
    context.Jobs.Add(job);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // This method is what I want to do in the background 
    MonitorStatus(job);

    return Respond(response);
}

private async Task MonitorStatus(Job job)
{
    bool isDone = false;

    while (!isDone)
    {
        isDone = await IsDone(job.Urn);

        if (!isDone)
            await Task.Delay(10000);
    }

    string guid = await new JobRepository(job).GetGuid();

    // The line underneath throws an error because the context has been disposed
    (await context.Jobs.FindAsync(job.Id)).Finish(guid);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // ...
    // Notify the user
}
```

Comment: Does the Autodesk api offers [webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)?

Comment: Yes: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/.

Comment: Brilliant! https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-model-derivative/ Gonna look into this. Thanks!

Comment: You'll likely also want to look into SignalR, so you can notify the user when your webhook is hit.

Comment: Looking good, I will definitely use that. For development purposes I set up a Slack webhook, so I can receive messages internally, but SignalR will suit my needs for release :)

Answer (score 2):

Translation of files in [Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview) boils down to two main endpoints:

- [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST) for triggering the translation, and
- [GET manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) for getting the manifest of the translation (incl. its status while the translation is still running)

If you're making the HTTP requests yourself, you can just poll the manifest until you see that the translation has been completed.

If you're using the [Forge .NET SDK](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client), you can trigger the translation using the [Translate](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate) method, and poll the results using the [GetManifest](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#getmanifest) method.

Comment: I already implemented the POST job and GET manifest.

`bool isDone = false;

    while (!isDone)
    {
        isDone = await IsDone(job.Urn);

        if (!isDone)
            await Task.Delay(10000);
    }`

This part polls the manifest as you say. But my question is how to run this in the background, so the user can get back to his own thing and gets a notification when the manifest is done.

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like you respond to your user's request immediately after starting the status monitoring. That's good. If you want to provide some feedback mechanism to your users, you could have them provide an optional URL ("webhook") that you could call when the translation is complete.

Comment: Regarding the issue with `context` being disposed in the `MonitorStatus` method, that's an ASP.NET Core question that someone else can probably answer better than me, but I'd suggest that you don't really need to store the status of the translation because that information is already stored in the manifest. Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: That's a good point. I can prevent needing the context at that point. But I am now working on implementing a webhook, so that will take the need for monitoring the status myself away. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a Webhook of Autodesk Forge, which calls an endpoint that notifies the user that the conversion has been completed. This webhook contains a body with information about which job has been completed, so I can update the database accordingly.

This webhook removes the need for my `MonitorStatus(job)` method.

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/create-a-hook-model-derivative/